# Unable to get toolbars, reasonably-sized windows, and other things in TinyMCE 3.5.6 fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, editor

I am making changes to a set of forms that are using TinyMCE 3.5.6 as the WYSIWYG editor. One of the modifications I would like to make is to allow people to edit text in a separate window, and the ability to resize said window. With the following initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
tinyMCE.init({
    theme: "advanced",
    mode : "exact",
    plugins : "fullscreen",
    toolbar : "fullscreen",
    elements : "id_notes_type_of_organization, id_mission_statement, id_goals_and_impact",
    theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullscreen"
    });
});
```

I get fullscreen, but not in a separate window. If I subsequently add `fullscreen_new_window: true`, a new window opens but:

1. The toolbars are missing from the new window;
2. The window size is tiny and requires resizing;
3. Any text I type into this window does not carry over to the text field that I originally clicked "fullscreen" in.

I am not sure how to rectify #1 or #3.

Problem 2 seems to be evident on Chrome on Linux in particular; using Firefox 20 on Linux, or Chrome on OS X, clicking fullscreen provides an actual fullscreen window. (Even the behavior on Chrome for Linux does not appear to be consistent.)

But I wanted this to work in Chrome as well; to that end, I put the following in the previous `tinyMCE.init` statement, which failed to work:

```
fullscreen_settings: {
    theme_advanced_source_editor_width: 640,
    theme_advanced_source_editor_height: 480
}
```

The debugging console shows that when I try to open the new window, jQuery is somehow not loaded (to wit, I get the error "Load jQuery first!"). Inserting a reference to it in `fullscreen.htm` does not seem to rectify the situation -- I get the same errors.

This is one of my first forays into TinyMCE, and I am feeling a touch out of my depth at this point. Any assistance would be quite welcome.